# Netsuite trigger a script on inventory qty or bin info change

Tags: netsuite

Bin info or Inventory Qty change for an inventory item, I need to fire a suitscript. it needs to cover any way that inventory will be adjusted, PO received, Sales Orders, manual adjustments, etc.

I tried attaching a userevent script but it didnt get called on PO being created and receving items on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a UserEvent script to every transaction type that affects user inventory. Your post doesn't say what "it" is that you attached your user event script to. Was it on Item Receipt?

Also as far as I know there is no User Event script for Inventory Worksheets so whatever you do you'll need some sort of manual reconciliation to pull current quantities.

Transactions that affect inventory include:

- Assembly Build
- Assembly Unbuild
- Bin Putaway Worksheet
- Bin Transfer
- Inventory Adjustment
- Inventory Distribution
- Inventory Transfer
- Inventory Worksheet
- Invoice*
- Cash Sale*
- Item Fulfillment
- Item Receipt
- Purchase Order**
- Return Authorization
- Sales Order^
- Transfer
- Transfer Order^
- Work Order^

* can cause changes to inventory when not sourced from a Sales Order

** May cause changes to inventory depending on your features/version and system configuration.

^ can cause changes to commited/available amounts depending on status.